# Audio is partly distorted after rendering video in blender

Tags: audio, blender

So I'm working in Blender 2.79b to merge a few videos together for a project and I have added a background track. Everything is absolutely smooth in the editor itself but after I render and export it, the first few seconds of the background track sound more distorted than my grandfather's old radio. The file format is FFmpeg, video codec is H.264 in MP4 and audio codec is AAC. Please tell me a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved. If anyone else encounters a similar problem, try turning down the volume of the soundtrack before rendering it.